# How to lock a row in a react material-table (with remote data) on edit?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Using [material-table](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table) i try to lock a row on the server
using a remote api call with a value from the edited row, like an id column, as soon as the user clicks the edit action button on that row.

The `onRowUpdate()` callback is called when the data is to be written, so too late to be useful here.

What can be used to achieve this pre-Edit callback?

Overriding `EditRow` somehow...?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet perfect but seems the way to go:

add a new state

```js
const [lock, setLock] = useState({});
```

and

```js
components={{
  EditRow: (props) => <MyTableEditRow onEdit={applyLock} offEdit={removeLock} {...props} />,
}}
```

to the tabel definition and a new Component `MyTableEditRow`

```js
const MyTableEditRow = (props) => {
  const { onEdit, offEdit, ...rest } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('MyTableEditRow useEffect');
    if (onEdit && typeof onEdit === 'function') onEdit(props.data);
    return () => {
      console.log('MyTableEditRow cleanup');
      if (offEdit && typeof offEdit === 'function') offEdit(props.data);
    };
  }, [onEdit, offEdit, props.data]);
  return <MTableEditRow {...rest} />;
};
```

this components is a small wrapper around the built in edit row component and  calls the two given function on create and destroy respectively who should get and remove the lock.

with the two callback to do the lock stuff on the rmeote api like: (add some error handling and stuff, `getLock()` and `deleteLock()` are basically axios calls to the  remote api...)

```js
  const applyLock = (rowData) => {
      getLock(api, rowData._id).then((lock_data) => {setLock(lock_data);})
    }
  };

  const removeLock = () => {
      deleteLock(api, lock).then((r) => { setLock({}); });
    }
  };
```

**TODO**

What is not working right now is `onRowDelete()`. the cancel button works, but the save just does nothing. Adding a row works, strangely...

**EDIT**

onRowDelete works, bug in my code.(do not use a non-existing state...)